# App has stopped Error Logcat error

Tags: java, android, indexoutofboundsexception

I am kinda new to adt and developing java apps. But I am trying to make a quiz game. For some reason though, when I click some button, it randomly says Unfortunately your app has stopped.

But the problem is, it does't happen at the same place. I happens on the actual quiz part) and even sometimes on the home screen.

I do notice that there are some log cat errors but since I am new, I don't know how to fix it.

For the first picture, here is the log cat error:

```
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at vApp.theperiodictablequiz.QuizActivity.ansGen(QuizActivity.java:131)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at vApp.theperiodictablequiz.QuizActivity$4.onClick(QuizActivity.java:204)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4206)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17357)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-14 18:22:27.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7346):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

For the second picture, here is the log cat errors:

```
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{vApp.theperiodictablequiz/vApp.theperiodictablequiz.QuizActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=7
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=7
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at vApp.theperiodictablequiz.QuizActivity.ansGen(QuizActivity.java:131)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at vApp.theperiodictablequiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:56)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-14 18:22:13.146: E/AndroidRuntime(7138):     ... 11 more
```

If any code is needed, please tell me and I will put it up. Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

Here is the code

```
    package vApp.theperiodictablequiz;

    import java.util.Random;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuizActivity extends Activity
{
    Button Answer1;
    Button Answer2;
    Button Answer3;
    Button Answer4;
    TextView Question;
    String correctAnswer="";
    int qindex=0;



    String[] QuestionArray =
    {"HelloBye", "What element has atomic number 1?",
            "What is the second most abundant element on Earth?",
            "Element with symbol Li ?", "Has 4 protons?" };
    String[] AnswerArray =
    { "Enter the Lion","Hydrogen", "Helium", "Lithium", "Beryllium", "Boron", "Carbon",
            "Nitrogen" };




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);




        Answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Answer1);
        Answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Answer2);
        Answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Answer3);
        Answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Answer4);
        Question= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Answer1.setOnClickListener(Achecker1);
        Answer2.setOnClickListener(Achecker2);
        Answer3.setOnClickListener(Achecker3);
        Answer4.setOnClickListener(Achecker4);



        ansGen();

    }


    public void ansGen()
    {
        int AnsArraylen=AnswerArray.length;     
        Random randomizer=new Random();
        int[] AnsVal=new int[4];
        int numchecker=0;

        for (int x=0;x<4;x+=1)
        {
            int tempVal=randomizer.nextInt((AnsArraylen));

            if (tempVal==AnsVal[0])
            {
                numchecker=1;
            }       
            if (tempVal==AnsVal[1])
            {
                numchecker=1;
            }
            if (tempVal==AnsVal[2])
            {
                numchecker=1;
            }
            if (tempVal==AnsVal[3])
            {
                numchecker=1;
            }

            if (numchecker==1)
            {
                x-=1;
            }

            if (numchecker==0)
            {
                AnsVal[x]=tempVal;
                numchecker=0;
            }
            numchecker=0;
        }
        Answer1.setText(AnswerArray[AnsVal[0]]);
        Answer2.setText(AnswerArray[AnsVal[1]]);
        Answer3.setText(AnswerArray[AnsVal[2]]);
        Answer4.setText(AnswerArray[AnsVal[3]]);
        int qpick=randomizer.nextInt(4);


        if(qpick==0)
        {
            qindex=AnsVal[0];
            correctAnswer=AnswerArray[AnsVal[0]];
        }
        if(qpick==1)
        {
            qindex=AnsVal[1];
            correctAnswer=AnswerArray[AnsVal[1]];
        }
        if(qpick==2)
        {
            qindex=AnsVal[2];
            correctAnswer=AnswerArray[AnsVal[2]];
        }
        if(qpick==3)
        {
            qindex=AnsVal[3];
            correctAnswer=AnswerArray[AnsVal[3]];
        }

        Question.setText(QuestionArray[qindex]);

        //Quesgen(qindex);
    }

    View.OnClickListener Achecker1 = new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("Button1");
            if(Answer1.getText()==correctAnswer)
            {
                System.out.println("YESYESYESYESYESYESYE1");
                ansGen();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Fail1");
            }
        }
    };


    View.OnClickListener Achecker2 = new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("Button2");
            if(Answer2.getText()==correctAnswer)
            {
                System.out.println("YESYESYESYESYESYESYE2");
                ansGen();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Fail2");
            }
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener Achecker3 = new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("Button3");
            if(Answer3.getText()==correctAnswer)
            {
                System.out.println("YESYESYESYESYESYESYE3");
                ansGen();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Fail3");
            }
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener Achecker4 = new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            System.out.println("Button4");
            if(Answer4.getText()==correctAnswer)
            {
                System.out.println("YESYESYESYESYESYESYE4");
                ansGen();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Fail4");
            }
        }
    };


    public void Quesgen(int qindex)
    {
        Question.setText(QuestionArray[qindex]);
    }




    public void delay()
    {
        for (long x = 1; x < 90000000; x += 1)
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see your main method?

Comment: Apparently, you are using an array that has less elements than the value you are trying to use. Please post the code in the `QuizActivity`

Comment: Yes the code is needed. Your problem is that you're trying to access an element of your array with an illegal index (either < 0 or >= array.length (the second option in your cases))

Comment: The index of an array is an integer value that resides in the interval [0, n-1], where n is the size of the matrix. If we request for an index that is either negative, or greater than or equal to the size of the array, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown.

Comment: You problem in AnsVal array. Your cycle assign number that is outside of the range of Answer array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is exception that called when you wanna get element from arrat that in out of the range of array.

For example (correct code for get last element of array:

```
int []array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int lastElement = array[8];
```

Incorrect code:

```
int []array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int lastElement = array[9];
```

Iteration in array is begin from 0 (don't 1 as in real life)

UPDATE 1

```
at vApp.theperiodictablequiz.QuizActivity.ansGen(QuizActivity.java:131)
```

Problem exception is called in 131 row

Comment: I know what it means I just am not sure where in my code it is an error. I though I checked already... Maybe I will check again.